# How to count all the similar dates in a separate column

Tags: r, datetime, count, aggregate, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to sum all of the similar Date/time rows into one row and a "count" row. Therefore I'll get two columns- one for the Date/Time and one for the count. 
I used this argument to round my observations into a 15 minute time period:
dat$by15 <- cut(dat$Date_Time, breaks = "15 min", )

I tried to use this argument, but it's "jumping" to a previous dataset and giving me the wrong observations for some reason:

dat <- aggregate(dat, by = list(dat$by15),  length )

Thank you guys !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You need to use `ave` i.e. `with(dat, ave(seq_along(by15), by15, FUN = length))`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but if you are trying to group by date and count observations for each date it's really simple

```
library(dplyr)

grouped_dates <- dat %>% 
  group_by(Date_Time) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but as the same as the argument I wrote the output that I get when running it is :
by15                               count
2014-06-01 00:00:00        12
2014-06-01 00:00:15        10
2014-06-01 00:00:30         7
.
.
.
When the original data is :
by15                               
2014-06-01 00:00:00        
2014-06-01 00:00:00      
2014-06-01 00:03:30
2014-06-01 00:06:45